# LSI MegaRaid - get HDD temperature

Tags: physical-environment, megaraid

Is there any way to get a drive temperature using MegaCLI or any other utility? Like "tw_cli /cx/px show temperature" in 3ware.

OS: Solaris x86.

Answer (score 2):

With megacli 8.02.16 (and maybe older versions, who knows), I found this info per-drive with:

```
megacli -PDInfo -aALL
```

Each drive has a line like:

> Drive Temperature :26C (78.80 F)

Answer (score 2):

On a newer version of MegaCLI (get it from http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5082327) you will get drive temp, with -PDList, tested on my servers. The additional problem would be the fact that for controller temp (also important) you need to have a temp sensor in place (it seems it does not come with one, at least AdpAllInfo says that)

Answer (score 1):

You could try accessing the SMART data with [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki). According to their docs, LSI is supported.

Comment: Unfortunately not in Solaris

Comment: smartmontools in Solaris, or LSI Megaraid support in Solaris?

Comment: smartmontools. and LSI megaraid. according of the response from the LSI support, standard megaraid utilites are unable to get temperatures yet. In Linux it's possible with smartmontools (told by the author, but in practice neither -d 3ware,N with 3ware nor -d megaraid,N with LSI cards work properly)

Comment: disserman: I have a 3ware controller with SLES 11, and it's working fine here.

Comment: Partly commenting in case I need to find this later :)

On Linux, Smartmontools doesn't seem to work with newer SAS LSI raid controllers, but a small kernel hack exposes the drives so that you can run smartmontools. Possibly dangerous. Don't do it ;)

in drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_sas.c:

Change megasas_slave_configure so that "if (sdev->channel < MEGASAS_MAX_PD_CHANNELS && sdev->type == TYPE_DISK)" performs "sdev->no_uld_attach = 1; sdev->writeable = 0;" instead of "return -ENXIO;"

Then run smartctl -a /dev/sgX on the new sg devices.

Answer (score 1):

With `MegaCLI SAS RAID Management Tool  Ver 8.07.10 May 28, 2013` it is:

```
megacli -PDList -aAll | grep Temperature
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some [documentation](http://www.lsi.com/DistributionSystem/AssetDocument/80-00156-01_RevF.pdf) on the MegaRaidCLI, check out page 176. Does running `MegaCli –PDInfo -PhysDrv[E0:S0,E1:S1....] -aN|-a0,1,2|-aALL` (with proper parameters) return the temperature? I really couldn't find much else.

e.g., `MegaCli -PhysDrv[E0:S0] -aALL`?

Comment: Nope.  -pdinfo includes only some very elementary SMART data.